# How to Integrate prettier-js.el into spacemacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, spacemacs, code-editor, prettier

I'm trying to get [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/tree/master/editors/emacs) working in spacemacs.

I have `(prettier-js :location (recipe :url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prettier/prettier/master/editors/emacs/prettier-js.el" :fetcher url))` which is somewhat working, but then in *Messages* I see

```
Contacting host: raw.githubusercontent.com:443
Wrote /Users/travis/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/build/prettier-js/prettier-js.el
File: /Users/travis/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/build/prettier-js/prettier-js.stamp
Error getting PACKAGE-DESC: (search-failed ;;; prettier-js.el ends here)
Cannot load prettier-js
```

I don't know enough emacs yet to know know what a PACKAGE-DESC does, or if I need it to get prettier to load.

I'm trying to do this in a private layer

The docs say:

> Add this to your init

```
(require 'prettier-js)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'prettier-before-save)))
```

I think I should have something like:

```
(defun myJS/post-init-prettier-js ()
  "Initialize prettier-js"
  (use-package prettier-js)
  :defer t
  :init
  (progn
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'prettier-before-save)
    )
  )
```

in my layer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the commit [9d2a108](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/2c21d5098ae346c3a15521bfa4681e17ab0794c9) Spacemacs comes with a layer that adds support for Prettier. You can use it today if you're using the `develop` branch of Spacemacs or if you're reading this in the future and are using version 0.300 or something more recent.

To use it simply add `prettier` as a layer in the list of layers specified by `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. Additionally you should enable Prettier as a formatter for the layers for the languages in which you want to use Prettier. How to do this is documented in the specific layers. For JavaScript you should add the following to your `dotspacemacs/user-init`.

```
(setq javascript-fmt-tool 'prettier)
```

With the above configuration the JavaScript layer will user Prettier to format JavaScript files.

Comment: spacemacs javascript layers have been seeing some updates lately :)

Comment: Is it possible to set prettier to run on save?

Comment: @fraxture As long as the `prettier-js` mode is active, then format-on-save should work by default.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few steps that we need to perform in order to activate `prettier` in **Spacemacs**:

---

**1. Install `prettier` integration in Spacemacs:**

- `<SPC> <SPC>` (press the spacebar key twice), this will trigger **HELM** allowing us to search for Emacs commands.
- After pressing `<SPC> <SPC>`, type `package-install` in the **HELM** buffer and press `<RET>` (the Return/Enter key).
- A list of packages will appear inside the **HELM Package Install** buffer, type `prettier-js` in it and press `<RET>`.

---

**2. Install `prettier` in your system:**

- The integration doesn't do anything without `prettier` itself.
- Assuming you already have `node` and `npm` installed, go to your terminal and type: `npm install -g prettier` and press enter.

---

**3. (Optional) Setup automatic format on save:**

- Open your `.spacemacs` config file by pressing `<SPC> <f> <e> <d>`.
- Find the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section of it and type the following snippet inside of it:

  `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
    (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
    (add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
  )`
- Save the settings' change by pressing `<SPC> <f> <s>`
- Reload the saved settings by pressing `<SPC> <f> <e> <R>`

Comment: Worked for me, using Spacemacs @ tip of `develop` which is currently commit `00e870815`.

Answer (score 4):

The prettier-js package is now on melpa to install it add prettier-js to dotspacemacs-additional-packages in your spacemacs file.

Comment: I used the updated answer and I get this "Package prettier-js is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?" any advice?